# Trigger quest updating a column as data is entered in multiple columns at different times

Tags: mysql-5.5

What I am looking at is I have a project I'm doing and within it there is to be a column that would be turned into a GPA based off their individual assignment scores.

My question is would it be possible to utilize a trigger to get that to update this GPA column when each assignment score is entered?

If it is how would I go about doing this?

I know this would be an on update trigger I'm just clueless as to the rest of it due to the data it would be working off of is from multiple columns or will be by the end of a student's term. If more info is needed please let me know.